# Get OleDbDataReader  object to accept null values when reading from a spreadsheet

Tags: c#, datareader

Is there a way to have an OleDbDataReader accept null values when reading from an excel spreadsheet? We have the following columns:

ID | CourseCode | CourseHours | State | EffectiveDate | ExpirationDate

Occasionally the CourseHours column will be blank. This screws up my code since instead of reader[2] being null, reader[2] = State.

This is the method I am using right now but it seems a bit cumbersome.

```
OleDbDataReader reader;
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();


    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string Id = "";
        string courseCode = "";
        string hours = "";
        string state = "";
        string effectiveDate = "";
        string expirationDate = "";
        string method = "";


        //Add manadatory values
        Id = reader[0].ToString();
        courseCode = reader[1].ToString();

        int value = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(reader[2].ToString(), out value))
        {
            hours = value.ToString();
            state = reader[3].ToString();
            effectiveDate = reader[4].ToString();

            //Check for null in expiration date
            if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(reader[5]))
            {
                expirationDate = reader[5].ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            state = reader[2].ToString();
            effectiveDate = reader[3].ToString();

            //Check for null in expiration date
            if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(reader[5]))
            {
                expirationDate = reader[5].ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the snippet of code that reads the values? It's not clear how your code works from the last line.

Comment: Try to access the data via column name (string) instead of index. That really only works if it recognizes the first row as the header though.  What does your connection string look like?  You might have to modify to recognize header info.